# Joining three tables sql with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am looking for a solution to the SQL problem I have, I have to display three totals for financial period in a row with appropriate headings, so far I have all the information displayed but it is in a column using union. I do not know where to put the joins or which type would be better suited, I would really appreciate help with this answer as I have been looking at it for a while.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(ComStatinYearTotal) 
     FROM tblComStatInYear 
     WHERE ComStatinYearYear = '2014' 
       AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd > '2014-07-01'
       AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd < '2014-09-30'
       AND ComStatInYearCltCode = 'STI02')
    - (SELECT SUM(ComStatinYearTotal)
       FROM tblComStatInYear 
       WHERE ComStatinYearYear = '2013' 
         AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd > '2013-07-01'
         AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd < '2013-09-30' 
         AND ComStatInYearCltCode = 'STI02') TotalDiff  

UNION

SELECT 
   (SELECT SUM(ComStatinYearPen) 
    FROM tblComStatInYear 
    WHERE ComStatinYearYear = '2014' 
      AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd > '2014-07-01'
      AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd < '2014-09-30' 
      AND ComStatInYearCltCode = 'STI02')
    - (SELECT SUM(ComStatinYearPen)
       FROM tblComStatInYear 
       WHERE ComStatinYearYear = '2013' 
         AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd > '2013-07-01'
         AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd < '2013-09-30' 
         AND ComStatInYearCltCode = 'STI02') PenDiff 

UNION

SELECT 
   (SELECT SUM(ComStatinYearPrin) 
    FROM tblComStatInYear 
    WHERE ComStatinYearYear = '2014' 
      AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd > '2014-07-01'
      AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd < '2014-09-30' 
      AND ComStatInYearCltCode = 'STI02')
   - (SELECT SUM(ComStatInYearPrin)
      FROM tblComStatInYear 
      WHERE ComStatinYearYear = '2013' 
        AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd > '2013-07-01'
        AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd < '2013-09-30' 
        AND ComStatInYearCltCode = 'STI02') PrinDiff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about your data, but you can do the following:

```
DECLARE @year2014(ComStatinYearTotal_SUM INT, ComStatinYearPen_SUM INT, ComStatinYearPrin_SUM INT)
DECLARE @year2013(ComStatinYearTotal_SUM INT, ComStatinYearPen_SUM INT, ComStatinYearPrin_SUM INT)
INSERT INTO @year2014
SELECT SUM(ComStatinYearTotal), SUM(ComStatinYearPen), SUM(ComStatinYearPrin)
FROM tblComStatInYear 
    WHERE ComStatinYearYear = '2014' 
    AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd > '2014-07-01'
    AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd < '2014-09-30'
    AND ComStatInYearCltCode = 'STI02';

INSERT INTO @year2013
SELECT SUM(ComStatinYearTotal), SUM(ComStatinYearPen), SUM(ComStatinYearPrin)
FROM tblComStatInYear 
WHERE ComStatinYearYear = '2013' 
    AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd > '2013-07-01'
    AND ComStatInYearWeekEnd < '2013-09-30' 
    AND ComStatInYearCltCode = 'STI02';

SELECT t1.ComStatinYearTotal_SUM-t2.ComStatinYearTotal_SUM INT, t1.ComStatinYearPen_SUM - t2.ComStatinYearPen_SUM INT, t1.ComStatinYearPrin_SUM - t2.ComStatinYearPrin_SUM
FROM @year2014 t1, @year2013 t2;
```

Illustration:

```
-- Declare TABLE variables
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (C1 INT, C2 INT, C3 INT);
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (C1 INT, C2 INT, C3 INT);

--Load values
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (100, 200, 300);
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (10, 20, 30);

-- Apply the Subtract
SELECT T1.C1-T2.C1, T1.C2-T2.C2, T1.C3-T2.C3
FROM @T1 T1, @T2 T2
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to solve your question is using subqueries:

```
select
  (select sum(x) from table1) as result1,
  (select sum(y) from table2) as result2,
  (select sum(z) from table3) as result3
```